# Is there a way to remove the graph lines on the side of a figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to remove the graph lines that come up on the side of my figure.

So far in my code I have:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# DATA
L = 0.1 #m, length of arm of cross
t = L/2 #m, thickness

# VECTORS OF COORDINATES OF THE CROSS
X = np.array([L, t/2, t/2, -t/2, -t/2, -L, -L, -t/2, -t/2, t/2, t/2, L, L])
Y = np.array([t/2, t/2, L, L, t/2, t/2, -t/2, -t/2, -L, -L, -t/2, -t/2, t/2])

# PLOT
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
ax.plot(X,Y,color='C1', linewidth=2.5)
ax.axis('equal')

circle2 = plt.Circle((L - t/2, 0), t/4, color='b', fill=False)
circle3 = plt.Circle((-L + t/2, 0), t/4, color='b', fill=False)
circle4 = plt.Circle((0, L-t/2), t/4, color='b', fill=False)
circle5 = plt.Circle((0, -L+t/2), t/4, color='b', fill=False)
circle6 = plt.Circle((0, 0), t/4, color='b', fill=False)

ax.add_patch(circle2)
ax.add_patch(circle3)
ax.add_patch(circle4)
ax.add_patch(circle5)
ax.add_patch(circle6)
plt.show()

axis_off = ax.axis('off')

fig.savefig('cross.eps',format='eps')
fig.savefig('cross.pdf',format='pdf')
```

I am looking towards removing the axis that come up on the sides of the figure, can this be done on python?

Comment: `axis_off = ax.axis('off')` should be before `plt.show()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with:

```
plt.axis('off')
```

prior to plt.show().